# Task Getting rejected due to max pool size in ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Application has configured Zuul and Eureka to route request to backend services and everything works fine until we do load testing.

I started executing with 10 concurrent request on our load test environment and getting forwarding error in zuul gateway, and cause was, thread pool was not able to allocate thread for future task and rejecting tasks, with below error.

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@70fe89b5 rejected from 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@25df1748[Running, pool size = 10, 
active threads = 10, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1502]
```

My wonder; Above cause, i see pool size was only 10 and 10 threads were buzy, practical since i was firing 10 consecutive requests.

But my corepoolsize should be much greater than what i experience here of count 10. what is causing my application limited to 10 pool size , can i increase the corepoolsize and maxpoolsize in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is which ThreadPool are you using?
You can define various ExecutorServices in Java, for example the Cached Thread Pool for a unknown Number of Threads, which will solve your problem (Example code of one of my projects):

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    for(FluentCreate create: creates) {
        pool.execute(()->{
            try {
                create.execute();
            } catch (JiraException | IOException | ParseException | RestException | URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
pool.shutdown();
pool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

If you are able to predict the number of tasks you can go with a Fixed Thread Pool.

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
```

Comment: we are not defining explicitly any thread pool in our application, we are going with default ThreadPoolExecutor. As i have shown in the error.

Comment: Is this ThreadPoolExecutor defined by Zuul or by you? Sorry wasn't able to see the full stack trace.

Comment: default Java executor

Comment: Can you give a code besipiel. I think we're talking at cross purposes. Good example for ThreadPoolExecutor in Java:
https://www.baeldung.com/thread-pool-java-and-guava

Comment: @pappu_kutty there's no such thing as a default Java executor

Comment: @ohlec this is why i was confused. *Can you give a code example (earlier)

Comment: Please explain how the task are getting executed, in case there are no default executor.  Since in my application, I didn't configure any threadpool Executor

Comment: I think you are just using this Zuul Framework for multi threading, are you? Or i can't understand what exactly is going on in your code, please try to give us some code for further understanding. Maybe the Framework is creating a Fixed threadpool Executor. Normally you always have to define a ExecutorService by yourself. Just look at the link i proposed, this will explain everything about the Java ExecutorService :  
https://www.baeldung.com/thread-pool-java-and-guava

Answer (score 3):

A `RejectedExecutionException` may be thrown by a ThreadPoolExecutor for a couple of reasons, according to the javadocs:

- If the request cannot be queued, and another pool thread cannot be created because this would exceed the `maxPoolSize`.
- If the `shutdown()` method has already been called on the executor.

Now you say that you are using "the default" Java executor, but it is a bit unclear what you mean by that.  (If you showed us how you obtain and use this executor, it would be easier to understand your problem!)

But the bottom line is that the pool size is unlikely to be the cause of your problems with rejected tasks.  If all workers are busy, tasks *should* be queued.

---

> but I see pool size is only 10, which is not ok in real [life] scenario

A pool size of 10 is fine in many real life scenarios.  But if it is not suitable for your scenario, you should consider creating an executor with a larger (or smaller) pool.

Comment: but i see pool size is only 10, which is not  ok in real time scenario

Comment: Ok I will implement custom executor. But 10 is very small number for real time scenario

Comment: IIRC, the default pool size is a function of the number of processors available to the JVM.  As such, it represents a sensible choice for real **life** scenarios.  (This question is nothing to do with ["real time"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time)!!)

Comment: @pappu_kutty a pool size of 10 does not mean that your application cannot handle more than 10 concurrent requests. As StephenC said, all requests will be handled, they just might be in the queue for some time.

Comment: @ohlec,  yes.  All request should be handled,  but are they in concurrent scenario with same processing time.  My question is,  do I need to increase my core and max pool size by having custom implementation?

Comment: @pappu_kutty - We can't answer that.  It depends on your application.  It depends on the size and nature tasks that you are running.  It depends on how many cores you currently have.  It depends on how you get the executor and how you use it ... *which you haven't shown us* !!